# My androidstudio cannot push to github

Tags: git, android-studio, github, connection, push

it's my first time I used AndroidStudio to push my code to github and there were some problems that I cannot push to github .

I shared project on github successfully by AndroidStudio but it pushed unsuccessfully and I have tried many ways to solve it and they didn't work.

Here are some my problem pictures:

[shared successfully but pushed failed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hpHKj.png)

[my github test was successful][2]

[git test was successful][3]

[ssh was also ok](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tG5j5.png)

so how can I solve it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use ssh key you should use the ssh access protocol instead of https protocol. You should change the url to the format:

```
git@github.com:[user]/[proyect].git
```

I hope this helps :D

Comment: Yeah,it helped me out  ,THKS  A  LOT!

Comment: where should i make the change?

Comment: @ShubhamAgarwalBhewanewala you shoud use is in clone command, for example ```git clone git@github.com:[user]/[proyect].git```

Comment: Thanks for answering. I dont know what actually the problem was while using android studio. But I made it working using git bash and the android studio responded well.

Answer (score 0):

yes,I changed the url's format and did some other work .

```
git@gihub.com:[user]/[proyect].git
```

and except that ,you should notice that you should pull first and then push if you are first push

```
git pull origin master
```

then

```
git push -u origin master
```

finally ,I did it! GOOD LUCK!